# How to Convert Array into Object in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

Hi First i am getting dat from database as an array then I want to convert my array data into object I tried many function but not work in laravel api .I want to convert array data into object and return as `JSON` for `API` i google it several time but did not find any solutions any body help thanks in advance.

for api i am using this

```
return response()->json(['data' => $categories, 'status_code' => 200, 'status' => true],200);
```

i have tried

cateogry is an array `$categories`

```
    $data_object = (object)$categories; 
    $data_array = (array)$categories;
```

dd($data_array);
dd($data_object);

both return same result

this is the result

```
 array:14 [
  37 => array:5 [
    "id" => 37
    "name" => "Red abya"
    "alias" => "red-abya"
    "is_featured" => 0
  ]
  38 => array:5 [
    "id" => 38
    "name" => "Black Dress"
    "alias" => "black-dress"
    "is_featured" => 0
  ]"is_featured" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Abayas"
    "alias" => "abayas"
    "is_featured" => 1
    "sub_categories" => array:2 [
      0 => array:5 [
        "id" => 37
        "name" => "Red abya"
        "alias" => "red-abya"
        "is_featured" => 0
      ]
      1 => array:5 [
        "id" => 36
        "name" => "White abaya"
        "alias" => "white-abaya"
        "is_featured" => 0
      ]
    ]
  ]
  25 => array:5 [
    "id" => 25
    "name" => "Discount"
    "alias" => "discount"
    "is_featured" => 0
  ]
]
```

Comment: Check whether `$categories;` is array or not?

Comment: result is showing clearly and array

Comment: The way you posted the data makes it look like a json encoded string.  Please check to make sure it is indeed an array.  You can use the `is_array()` function to test this.

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want JSON at the end you can try changing this:

```
$data_object = (object)$categories;
```

to

```
$data_object = (object)$categories;
$data_object->toJson();
dd($data_object);
```

I will assume `$categories` is a collection array. Then in your view you can `json_encode($data_object)` it.

Comment: @ShahidHussain then this will work for you. Let me know if there is any error.

Comment: the above result section in returning

Comment: Are you sure you are not converting it back to array?  `$data_object = (object)$categories; 
    $data_array = (array)$categories;` you should just use Object but in the 2nd line you are again converting to array?

Comment: use these two $data_object = (object)$categories; $data_array = (array)$categories;  one by one not at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$categories = array_map(function($categories){
    return (object)$categories;
}, $categories);
```

Comment: i just want to convert the $category array to object bro

Answer (score -1):

if you use postman you send and receive data in json format. so for this you can use json_encode() to convert data to json format and json_decode() to convert data to array() format. also in laravel you get data by Request instans and send response by response() helper, so if you need get data in array format you can use this:
$data_array = (array)$request->all()
and for send data use:
response()->json($data_array , 200);

if you want stdclass use (object) instead array

Comment: look my function for request like this: public function test(Request $req){$data_array = (array)$req->all(); return response()->json(['data' => $data_array],200); }

Comment: code is returning perfect result which i want but i just want to convert into object that is all bro

Comment: object(stdClass)#257 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["name"]=>
  string(15) "ifoooooooooooo"
  ["code"]=>
  string(3) "500"
} this is my result after use (object) for casting for $request->all()